# How to save font alterations?

Tags: fonts

Let's say I have this in the buffer:

> 'BE BOLD'

I select it and type `Alt-o b`. It is now displayed as **'BE BOLD'** I Save, quit, reopen: The font change is lost. How to keep the font change, please?

Comment: Do you enable [Enriched Mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Enriched-Mode.html)?

Comment: That answers the question, thanks.

Comment: @muffinmad: Please consider posting that as an answer, with a bit of explanation (summary), so it's not a link-only answer (which would be rejected). Comments can be deleted at any time. The aim is to have specific questions and answers, to help others too. Thx.

Comment: @Drew Ok. It was just a clarifying comment :)

Comment: @muffinmad: It seems like a (good) answer, to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save text formatting properties use [`enriched-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Enriched-Mode.html). Your file will be saved using [`text/enriched` MIME format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enriched_text) and will be looks like this:

```
Content-Type: text/enriched
Text-Width: 70

<bold>BE BOLD</bold>
```

Visiting such file will enable `enriched-mode` and restore text properties.